# SDL ECL connector timeouts/connectivity

Tags: ecl, sites-9.1

We're running into an issue where we have an ECL connector that connects to a DAM session is expiring or is killing the CMS.  I'm hoping someone can answer the following questions.

Does Sites create the connection to ECL at startup or sites create the connection at User interaction time (first person clicks the ECL connector?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "Does Sites create the connection to ECL...".  Which connection, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The connection from Sites to ECL is completely configurable in your manifest file. Are you using a connector from the AppStore or build one from scratch? If it is the latter, you should probably look to setup OAUTH or supported authorization with the third-party DAM. You can mention accesstoken in your manifest file.

For example, [online documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/842462/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/setting-up-the-------------connector-for------------------aprimo-dam) shows how an Aprimo DAM connector can be configured with Sites 9.1 and its [limitations](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/850599/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/connector-for------------------aprimo-dam-------------------limitations) as well.